# Appending the html code (i.e. svg) via jquery is not shown in the UI

Tags: jquery, html, dom, svg

I have an html as follows

```
<svg>    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> abc </text>
    </g>

    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> def </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

then i selected the g tag which has the child "text tag" and its value " abc " and appended some other text tags to it using jquery as follow

```
$('g:has(text:contains(" abc "))').append($('<text />', { text: ' extra added abc ' }));
```

, such that the final output will be

```
    <svg>
    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> abc </text>
        <text> extra added abc </text>
    </g>

    <g>
        <rect></rect>
        <text> def </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

But the issue is the newly added text (i.e.  extra added abc  ) is **not** shown in the UI but the dom object is added in the html code (checked in the debugger tool of chrome)?

Comment: it may be display : none

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird: no, the output is as above which doesnot have display:none

Answer (score 0):

use

```
svg.append("text");
```

This is valid syntax , Else browser will not understand what is `svg text`

```
$('g:has(text:contains(" abc "))').append("text");
```